# Possible to achieve mass redirect in SharePoint? Some IIS function? Something else?

Tags: 2010, redirect

For example,

x/SiteDirectory/governingboard/handbook/
and anything under it needs to redirect
x/about/gov/handbook

x/SiteDirectory/emphandbook/
and anything under it needs to redirect 
x/depts/hr/x-employee-handbook

Is there a way to do this inside Sharepoint, a setting on the page of the original address? or do I have to do this on the server directly? Or is there a third party program?

Comment: You can use ISA server for redirecting, if you got one in your farm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. Add a javascript redirect in a content editor web part on the pages you want to be redirected.
2. Edit the master page currently in use and create a javascript function to redirect the user according to the current URL.

But if you have ISA or TMG, rather implement a rule on there to handle the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use IIS Url Rewrite to do the redirects:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

But: If you have several servers, you have to do it multiple times!